# $exp$ of Half-Normal Distribution

Tags: probability-distributions, stochastic-processes, normal-distribution, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion

I know that the Half-Normal Distribution has moments of all orders - that is, if $X\sim\mathcal{N}(\mu,\sigma)$, then,
$$ E[|X|^p]<\infty $$
However, do we also have
$$ E[e^{|X|}]<\infty $$
? Thank you in advance!

Comment: At least for zero-mean Gaussians, it is well known that $\mathbb{E}e^{\alpha X^{2}}$ is finite for some $\alpha>0$. That is Fernique's theorem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume $X \sim N(\mu,\sigma^2)$. The distribution of $|X|$ is called a folded normal distribution. Its moment generating function is (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Folded_normal_distribution)

$$\mathbb{E}[e^{t|X|}]=e^{\frac{\sigma^2t^2}{2}+\mu t}\Phi(\frac{\mu}{\sigma}+\sigma t)+e^{\frac{\sigma^2t^2}{2}-\mu t}\Phi(-\frac{\mu}{\sigma}+\sigma t)$$

Here $\Phi$ is the CDF of the standard normal distribution. Hence

$$\mathbb{E}[e^{|X|}]=e^{\frac{\sigma^2t^2}{2}+\mu}\Phi(\frac{\mu}{\sigma}+\sigma)+e^{\frac{\sigma^2}{2}-\mu}\Phi(-\frac{\mu}{\sigma}+\sigma) < \infty$$